# Spring-Data-JPA - Infinite recursion after inserting one record to database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Get, Post and Update HTTP requests to the controller works well for the first time (When the corresponding database table is empty) but after inserting one record to database all requests get into infinite recursion

this is my schema:
[image]

the problem is with `TripRequestController` that deals with the `Request` table at the top left of the schema

I think the problem comes from `Request_modification` table just bellow the `Request` table

The following is the `Request` Entity

```java
package com.eventumsolutions.estrips.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="request")
public class TripRequest {


    public TripRequest() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Req_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="Start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name="End_date")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(name="Destination")
    private String destination;

    @Column(name="Two_way")
    private Boolean twoWay;

    @Column(name="Expected_duration")
    private Integer expectedDuration;

    @Column(name="Arrival_time")
    private Time arrivalTime;

    @Column(name="Suggested_pickup_time")
    private Time suggestedPickupTime;

    @Column(name="Seats")
    private Integer seats;

    // don't apply cascading deletes
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="Modified_by")
    private Employee modifiedBy;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(
            name ="request_has_employee",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Req_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Emp_id")
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id.request",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private RequestProcess requestProcess;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id.parentRequest",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private RequestModification requestModificationAsParent;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id.childRequest",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private RequestModification requestModificationAsChild;

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        if (employees == null) {
            employees = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        employees.add(employee);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public Boolean getTwoWay() {
        return twoWay;
    }

    public void setTwoWay(Boolean twoWay) {
        this.twoWay = twoWay;
    }

    public Integer getExpectedDuration() {
        return expectedDuration;
    }

    public void setExpectedDuration(Integer expectedDuration) {
        this.expectedDuration = expectedDuration;
    }

    public Time getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    public void setArrivalTime(Time arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    public Time getSuggestedPickupTime() {
        return suggestedPickupTime;
    }

    public void setSuggestedPickupTime(Time suggestedPickupTime) {
        this.suggestedPickupTime = suggestedPickupTime;
    }

    public Integer getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }

    public void setSeats(Integer seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public Employee getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(Employee modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public RequestProcess getRequestProcess() {
        return requestProcess;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setRequestProcess(RequestProcess requestProcess) {
        this.requestProcess = requestProcess;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public RequestModification getRequestModificationAsParent() {
        return requestModificationAsParent;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setRequestModificationAsParent(RequestModification requestModificationAsParent) {
        this.requestModificationAsParent = requestModificationAsParent;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public RequestModification getRequestModificationAsChild() {
        return requestModificationAsChild;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setRequestModificationAsChild(RequestModification requestModificationAsChild) {
        this.requestModificationAsChild = requestModificationAsChild;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("request hnaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        return "TripRequest{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", startDate=" + startDate +
                ", endDate=" + endDate +
                ", destination='" + destination + '\'' +
                ", twoWay=" + twoWay +
                ", expectedDuration=" + expectedDuration +
                ", arrivalTime=" + arrivalTime +
                ", suggestedPickupTime=" + suggestedPickupTime +
                ", seats=" + seats +
                ", modifiedBy=" + modifiedBy +
//              ", employees=" + employees +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the following is the `RequestModification` Entity

```java
package com.eventumsolutions.estrips.entity;

import org.apache.coyote.Request;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="request_modification")
public class RequestModification {

   public RequestModification(){

   }

   @EmbeddedId
   private RequestModificationKey id;

   public RequestModificationKey getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(RequestModificationKey id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

}
```

And this is `RequestModificationKey`:

```java
package com.eventumsolutions.estrips.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class RequestModificationKey  implements Serializable {

   public RequestModificationKey(){

   }

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="Parent_req_id", referencedColumnName = "Req_id")
   private TripRequest parentRequest;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="Child_req_id", referencedColumnName = "Req_id")
   private TripRequest childRequest;

   public TripRequest getParentRequest() {
       return parentRequest;
   }

   public void setParentRequest(TripRequest parentRequest) {
       this.parentRequest = parentRequest;
   }

   public TripRequest getChildRequest() {
       return childRequest;
   }

   public void setChildRequest(TripRequest childRequest) {
       this.childRequest = childRequest;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       RequestModificationKey that = (RequestModificationKey) o;
       return Objects.equals(parentRequest, that.parentRequest) &&
               Objects.equals(childRequest, that.childRequest);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(parentRequest, childRequest);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       System.out.println("mod hnaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
       return "RequestModificationKey{" +
               "parentRequest=" + parentRequest +
               ", childRequest=" + childRequest +
               '}';
   }
}
```

finally, this is my controller:

```java
package com.eventumsolutions.estrips.controller;

import com.eventumsolutions.estrips.entity.TripRequest;
import com.eventumsolutions.estrips.entity.Employee;
import com.eventumsolutions.estrips.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.eventumsolutions.estrips.repository.TripRequestRepository;
import com.eventumsolutions.estrips.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api")
@CrossOrigin
public class RequestController {

    @Autowired
    private TripRequestRepository tripRequestRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/tripRequests")
    public Page<TripRequest> getTripRequests(Pageable pageable) {
        return tripRequestRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @PostMapping("/tripRequests")
    public TripRequest createTripRequest(@Valid @RequestBody TripRequest tripRequest) {
        Long empId = 1L;
        return employeeRepository.findById(empId)
                .map(employee -> {
                    tripRequest.setModifiedBy(employee);
                    return tripRequestRepository.save(tripRequest);
                }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found with id " + empId));
    }

    @PutMapping("/tripRequests/{tripRequestId}")
    public TripRequest updateTripRequest(@PathVariable Long tripRequestId,
                              @Valid @RequestBody TripRequest tripRequestRequest) {
        Long empId = 1L;
        if(!employeeRepository.existsById(empId)) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found with id " + empId);
        }
        Optional<Employee> modifier = employeeRepository.findById(empId);
        tripRequestRequest.setModifiedBy(modifier.get());
        return tripRequestRepository.findById(tripRequestId)
                .map(tripRequest -> {
                    //[TODO]: employee cascading
                    tripRequest.setStartDate(tripRequestRequest.getStartDate());
                    tripRequest.setEndDate(tripRequestRequest.getEndDate());
                    tripRequest.setDestination(tripRequestRequest.getDestination());
                    tripRequest.setTwoWay(tripRequestRequest.getTwoWay());
                    tripRequest.setExpectedDuration(tripRequestRequest.getExpectedDuration());
                    tripRequest.setArrivalTime(tripRequestRequest.getArrivalTime());
                    tripRequest.setSuggestedPickupTime(tripRequestRequest.getSuggestedPickupTime());
                    tripRequest.setSeats(tripRequestRequest.getSeats());
                    tripRequest.setModifiedBy(tripRequestRequest.getModifiedBy());
                    return tripRequestRepository.save(tripRequest);
                }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("TripRequest not found with id " + tripRequestId));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/tripRequests/{tripRequestId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteTripRequest(@PathVariable Long tripRequestId) {
        return tripRequestRepository.findById(tripRequestId)
                .map(tripRequest -> {
                    tripRequestRepository.delete(tripRequest);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
                }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("TripRequest not found with id " + tripRequestId));
    }
}
```

All request to deal with `Request` table works fine while it's empty,
The first post request works well as well but then any HTTP request while the `Request` table contains one record causes an infinite recursion with the following error message

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.returns.AbstractExpandingFetchSource.getBidirectionalEntityReferences(AbstractExpandingFetchSource.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing equals and hashCode for all your entities to start of with. I've seen similar errors caused by default equals and hashCode methods.

[Refer to this article for useful information.](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I even solved it by changing some eager associations to lazy